# Can local variables and functions have the same names in C?

Tags: c

Suppose I have a **single** .c file in which I have a *local* variable **a**. Can I also have a *function* in that c file which has the *same* name **a**?

**EDIT:** If not, why?

Conceptually, the local variable is stored on **stack** and functions are stored in **text** section of memory. So there shouldn't be a problem right?

When I tried this, compiler gave error. I am wondering if this is compiler specific or it is actually an error.

Comment: The error is likely elsewhere.

Comment: can you specify the error

Comment: a cannot be used as a function, or something like that

Comment: @Dabo, yes that's the error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you have something like that:

```
void a (void)
{
    // whatever
}

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    a++; // no problem, boss
    a(); // <-- compiler tantrum: variable used as a function
    // whatever
}
```

The error you are getting is due to the fact that you are using `a` as a function.

Each time you open a curly brace, you define a new local scope, where you are free to redefine symbols that exist in a higher scope.

In that case, the identifier `a` inside the block is refering to a local variable, so you can't use it as a function.
`a` at toplevel is a function, but inside the block it is shadowed by the local variable definition with the same name.
It means you cannot call the function `a` from within that block (and any other embedded sub-blocks, for that matter). *(more precisely, you cannot access the function `a` by its name, but you could still call it by having a pointer to that function accessable from within that scope)*

This should be an incentive to define meaningful names for your functions and other global symbols, since they will have to coexist in the toplevel scope ***and*** run the risk of being shadowed by any lower scope symbols.

As other answers stated, there are mechanisms in other languages like C++ called "scope resolution modifiers" that allow to explicitely designate the scope of a symbol, but that does not exist in C.

Answer (score 6):

You cant because if you have example(), 'example' is a pointer to that function.

Comment: This is the right answer. There are function pointers, which are variables. But also, all function names are treated as const function pointers! So when you try to define your variable, there already exists a variable with the same name.

Comment: So where are these pointer variables stored? If it is **text** memory, it still shouldn't be an issue right?

Comment: Saying that *"'example' is a pointer to that function."* is incorrect. In this case 'example' will give you the function address, but there is no pointer variable.

Comment: @NicolasMiari This is **not** the right answer, because the OP explicitely speaks about a *local* variable, not a static global. A local variable will mask the global function name just like it would any symbol higher in the scope chain.

Comment: @user694733 small technicality, almost pedantic I would say. The symbol (function name) is treated as though there a const function pointer with the same name and signature. If you take your argument to the letter, there exist no 'variables' at all; only memory addresses. Treating some of them as variables is a high level, human-friendly (but artificial) construct.

Comment: @kuroineko You are right, I stand corrected. Your answer clarifies it very well.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Thanks for the compliment. The original question was a bit confusing anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare local variables with the same name as a global variable, but the local variable will *shadow* the global. As long as your local `a` is in scope, the symbol `a` refers to your local variable.

Some languages allow to refer to the global symbols via special syntax, such as `::a` or `.a`. C is not one of these languages.

(As a side note: You shouldn't give global functions names that are likely to interfere with locals. Names of locals are usually short and don't carry much information - it is not needed, bacause the context is clear. Global variables have to share one big namespace with other variables. It is recommended to provide a bit of context in your name in order to avoid name clashes and shadowing.)

Comment: If he is actually getting a compiler error, that means that a difference in scope is not helping avoid the collision. Perhaps his variable is file-global, hence at the same scope as all the function names.

Comment: @NicolasMiari, local variable with same name will also give a compiler error if he tries to actually call the function: `error: called object ‘abc’ is not a function` .

Comment: OK, so both will yield an error. I guess a local variable inside e.g. a `for` loop is no good either, because the scope of function names is 'pervasive'? (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: You can declare a symbol `a` in your routine and then another symbol with name `a` in another scope inside that routine, e.g. in the code block of a `for` loop, and so on. Only the symbol with the closest scope will be recognised. If you only have a local variable `a` in a loop scope, you can call the function `a()` outside that scope, but not when the local variable  `a` is visible. (GCC can warn you about shadowing with `-Wshadow`, but I'm surprised that this is not included in `-Wall` or even `-Wextra`.)

Answer (score 5):

Just for completion's sake, there is actually a way to refer to global identifiers, even if they are shadowed in C.

In kuroi neko's snippet, that would look like this:

```
void a (void)
{
    // whatever
}

{
    int a;

    a++; // no problem, boss
    {
         extern void a(void);
         a(); // no problem either
    }
}
```

I wouldn't do that though. Use proper names instead.