# Reducing code duplication while defining a commutative operation

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a a set of overloads of a commutative binary function named `overlap`, which accepts two distinct types:

```
class A a; class B b;
bool overlap(A, B);
bool overlap(B, A);
```

My function `overlap` returns true if and only if one shape overlaps the other - this is one common example used when discussing [multimethods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch).

Because `overlap(a, b)` is equivalent to `overlap(b, a)`, I only need to implement one "side" of the relation.  One repetitive solution is to write something like this:

```
bool overlap(A a, B b) { /* check for overlap */ }
bool overlap(B b, A a) { return overlap(a, b);   }
```

But I would prefer not to write an extra `N! / 2` trivial versions of the same function by allowing them to be generated instead, using a template.

```
template <typename T, typename U> 
bool overlap(T&& t, U&& u) 
{ return overlap(std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<T>(t)); }
```

Unfortuately, this is prone to recurse infinitely, which is not acceptable: see
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20851835593bd557

How can I prevent such infinite recursion?  Am I approaching the problem correctly?

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561407/c-how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-function-overloads -- puts the arguments in a tuple and then uses std::get() to pull them out in the "right" order.

Comment: Separate from the narrow scope, I expect in many cases the need to do this is a code smell. For example, should A and B not implement a shape interface/inherit from a parent class?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have an interface that is implemented by both of your classes, so you don't really need to care about class A and class B?
Or isn't this that easy in c++?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here's a simple fix:

```
template <typename T, typename U> 
void overlap(T t, U u)
{
    void overlap(U, T);
    overlap(u, t);
}
```

The template itself declares the target function, which will be preferred over recursion because it is an exact match (be sure to take care of constness and reference-ness in your real case). If the function has not been implemented, you get a linker error:

```
/tmp/cc7zinK8.o: In function `void overlap<C, D>(C, D)':
main.cpp:(.text._Z7overlapI1C1DEvT_T0_[_Z7overlapI1C1DEvT_T0_]+0x20):
    undefined reference to `overlap(D, C)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

... which points directly at the missing function :)

Comment: So, in this case do you need to declare a second function that check for the overlap?

Comment: @Vitor what do you mean?

Comment: We started with this two functions `bool overlap(A a, B b) { /* check for overlap */ }` and `bool overlap(B b, A a) { return overlap(a, b);   }`.  Now you propose a single function, but I don't see any code to check for overlap. I didn't understand this trick.  :s

Comment: @Vitor no, this only replaces the second one which swaps the arguments, of course you still need to implement at least one function of each pair to perform actual work :)

Comment: Note: it seems to me this only works for `overlap` functions in the same namespace.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yes. Locally-declared functions are strictly part of the enclosing namespace.

Comment: Well, that's not really nice. It only works if you never inherit from any of your shape-classes, or write the neccessary forwarders.

Comment: @Deduplicator example of first and second parts please?

Comment: @Quentin In his first take of closing the gap with a template, yes. But elsewhere, no.

Comment: @Deduplicator fair enough. I tried inejcting some SFINAE in the return type, but apparently the function template is able to refer to itself at that point already :/

Comment: Not detecting the error until link time could be a big downside for a large project with many source files.  Changing a `.h` can lead to a lot of files needing recompilation, so link-time might be a couple minutes of compilation away.  Hopefully this is easy to get right and isn't something that needs frequent re-adjustment in most code-bases.

Comment: This only works if the reference function is an exact match; you get a link error if, for example, the user implemented `bool overlap(const A&, const B&);`.

Answer (score 12):

As a wise man once said, there is no problem you cannot solve with an additional layer of indirection, except too many layers of indirection.

So, use SFINAE and some indirection to get it done:

```
template<class A, class B>
auto overlap(A&& a, B&& b)
-> decltype(overlap_impl('\0', std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b)))
{ return overlap_impl('\0', std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b)); }

template<class A, class B>
auto overlap_impl(int, A&& a, B&& b)
-> decltype(do_overlap(std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b)))
{ return do_overlap(std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b)); }

template<class A, class B>
auto overlap_impl(long, B&& b, A&& a)
-> decltype(do_overlap(std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b)))
{ return do_overlap(std::forward<A>(a), std::forward<B>(b)); }

// You can provide more choices if you want, for example to use member-functions.

// Implement `do_overlap(A, B)`, maybe with references, in at least one direction.
```

Comment: It's nicely symmetric. I like it.

Comment: @cat: If I could use the concepts TS, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the actual method to something like `overlap_impl` and call this one inside the template. I will break the recursion:

```
bool overlap_impl(A a, B b) { /* check for overlap */ }

template <typename T, typename U> 
bool overlap(T&& t, U&& u) 
{ return overlap_impl(std::forward<U>(u), std::forward<T>(t)); }

template<> bool overlap(A&& t, B&& u)
{ return overlap_impl(std::forward<A>(t), std::forward<B>(u)); }
```

Comment: You still need to forward the "right-way-around" calls to `overlap` towards `overlap_impl`.

Comment: Right, well this would require the template specialisation for the right-way-around case i guess.

Comment: You could add some SFINAE to create just two template functions for all types which automatically figure out which order to pass the arguments.