# gcc - error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, function, gcc, lvalue

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight){            
    lift_a_car = stick_length * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);
  }
  printf("%2.f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));
}
```

Hello, i started not long ago learning C and when i am trying to compile this kind of code it returns to me error in the type error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

I think it is mathematically correct so i do not know what might cause this kind of error.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: `lift_a_car` is a function, you can't assign anything to it. Did you mean to `return`?

Comment: Actually i mean to return the value of lift_a_car yes.

Comment: It looks like you try to put a function definition inside `main`, this is not allowed. Each function definition must be separate

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for contributing your question to Stack Overflow.

**Firstly,** in standard C, it is not allowed to define functions inside other functions. Some compilers, like gcc, may support this through extensions, but this is not portable. So instead of

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    // local functions are not allowed
    float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight)
    {
        lift_a_car=stick_length*human_weight/(human_weight+car_weight);
    }

    printf("%2.f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));
}
```

you should write

```
#include <stdio.h>

// now lift_a_car is declared as a global function
float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight) 
{
    lift_a_car=stick_length*human_weight/(human_weight+car_weight);
}

int main(){
    printf("%2.f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));
}
```

**Secondly,** (this is the actual source of your error), in the body of function `lift_a_car` you haven't declared `lift_a_car' as a variable identifier. For that you must write

```
float lift_a_car = stick_length * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);
```

This 'lift_a_car' is not the same as the function's name. This is a local variable of the function (in C, a variable and a function can have the same name).

**Thirdly,** you must return this variable from the function in order for the `printf` function in `main` to access it. This is done using the `return` keyword.

```
float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight) 
{
    float lift_a_car = stick_length * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);
    return lift_a_car;
}
```

**Fourthly,** in C, dividing an `int` by an `int` will always yield an `int`, even if the answer is a fraction (e.g. 5/2 equals 2, not 2.5, because the fractional part is cut off).
The line

```
float lift_a_car = stick_length * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);
```

will set variable `lift_a_car` to `0.000000`  if  `(human_weight + car_weight)` is larger than `stick_length * human_weight`, as will be the case when you call the `lift_a_car` function in `main` with arguments 2, 80, and 1400. To solve this, you must cast at least one variable in that expression as a `float`, like so:

```
float lift_a_car = (float) stick_length * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);
```

**Fifthly,** if your intention in the line

```
printf("%2.f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));
```

was to print the value returned by function `lift_a_car` up to 2 digits after the decimal point (a precision of 2), then you meant to write `%.2f`, not `%2.f`. The number before the dot is the field width, while the number after is the precision.

In the end, your corrected code should look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight) 
{
    float lift_a_car = (float) stick_length * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);
    return lift_a_car;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%.2f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
float lift_a_car(const int ,const int ,const int);
int main(){
    printf("%.2f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));
}
float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight){
    float numerator=stick_length*human_weight;
    float denomerator=(human_weight+car_weight);
    return numerator/denomerator;
}
```

`lift_a_car` is a `function` so you cannot assign a value to it.
Due to that assignment, the compiler reported an “lvalue” error.

When you divide `int` type with another `int` type, it will be use integer division. Due to that, use `float` or `double` type while dividing.

Answer (score 0):

In C, to provide a value for a function to return, you use a `return` statement:

```
float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight)
{
    return (double) stick_length * human_weight / (human_weight+car_weight);
}
```

In this code, I also inserted `(double)`. In your original code, the expression is computed using integer arithmetic. This causes the division to truncate the result to an integer, producing zero. By converting one of the operands to a floating-point type, `double`, the floating-point arithmetic is used, produce a result of about .108108 with the numbers you show.

Functions should be defined outside of other functions. Some compilers may support defining functions inside, but this is an extension and should be avoided in the absence of special needs. Normal C code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight)
{
    return (double) stick_length * human_weight / (human_weight+car_weight);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%.2f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));
}
```

In this code, I also changed “%2.f”, which says to ensure the numeric field is at least two characters wide, to “%.2f”, which says to display two digits after the decimal point, which seems more suitable for this example.

Answer (score -1):

This is completely wrong

```
lift_a_car = stick_length * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);
```

compiler is asking you for a **lvalue** because the **lvalue** `lift_a_car` you are using in this case is a function and this is not allowed in C for reference you can visit [Can local variables and functions have the same names in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325761/can-local-variables-and-functions-have-the-same-names-in-c#:%7E:text=You%20cant%20because%20if%20you,a%20pointer%20to%20that%20function.&text=You%20can%20declare%20local%20variables,refers%20to%20your%20local%20variable.).

what you need to do is something like this,

```
float _lift_a_car = stick_lenght * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);
```

or you can return the computed value and then later can store it in a local variable

```
return stick_lenght * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);
```

Hope this will work.

For your information,

> Nested function is not supported by C because we cannot define a function within another function in C. We can declare a function inside a function, but it’s not a nested function.

For reference you can visit [Nested Functions in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-functions-c/#:%7E:text=Nested%20function%20is%20not%20supported,it%27s%20not%20a%20nested%20function.)

Comment: Basically my goal is to create a function called lift_a_car which returns the value of the `lift_a_car = stick_lenght * human_weight / (human_weight + car_weight);` while the parameters for the variables of stick, human and car will be defined later on in printf.

Comment: okay, I got it let me give you the code for that just wait...

Comment: Thanks a lot, i can now move on to next problems. Have a good day.